# Get email address from Password Reset Token on Backand

Tags: backand

When user request for a password reset feature, user gets a email with reset token.
Is it possible to get email address from this token?
I get token something like this.

`?token=0980987-6a44-43c9-a48e-259d87966cdc`

Answer (score 0):

By default, laravel has a **password_resets** table. In that table we have **token** and **email** id. You can select email id from the table using the token

```
SELECT email FROM `password_resets` where token= <your_token>
```